# how to get unique array based of nested attribute using underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I have a json array like this :

```
myArray=[{ a:1,
          b:[{c:"x",d:"y"}, {c:"r", d:"s"}...]
         },
         { a:2,
          b:[c:"p",d:"q"}, {c:"x", d:"s"}...]
         }
         ...
        ]
```

Is it possible to get a subset of myArray with unique values of "c" using underscore.js?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do it:

```
_.chain(myArray)
 .pluck("b")
 .flatten()
 .pluck("c")
 .unique()
 .value()
```

Comment: Awesome, it works!, never thought it would be possible with the chain of functions like you suggested. Thanks!